# How to populate prime ng multi select with chips with default selected values

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using reactive forms with prime ng multi select. When I try to patchValue with the desired default value that is received from the service, it populates and check the checkboxes correctly, however the chips are not populated and the chips are not set.
How can I see the chips also in the multiselect?
I have tried to do this:

```
<p-multiSelect
      [options]="this.muscles"
      [showToggleAll]="false"
      formControlName="muscles"
      defaultLabel="Select Muscles"
      optionLabel="name"
      display="chip"
    ></p-multiSelect>



this.exerciseForm.patchValue(
          {
            muscles: this.muscleService.getExerciseMusclesNames(
              this.config.data.exerciseToEdit
            ),
          },
          { emitEvent: true }
        );
```

Comment: Which version PrimeNg is this V11?

Comment: version 11.0.0-rc.2

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-prepopulate?file=src/app/app.component.html) for setting patchValue and defaultValue with p-multiSelect and reactive form.